# Somtimes password entered in the email field with the email address when multiple tets cases execited through test.xml

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

i stared 100 test cases execution using test.xml file. After all 100 test cases execution some test cases failed because password value is entered with the email value[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb7bn.png)  in the email box. How can handle this issue? i am using following code for wait after launching browser-

```
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(URL);
```

Comment: Please share code snippet wherein you are entering username and password.

Comment: //my login script-
                        driver.get(URL);
   driver.findElement(By.id("login-email")).sendKeys(Email);
   driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(Password);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='submit']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, Just use explicit wait before entering a password.A script will be robust now.

```html
WebElement element = null;
driver.get(URL);
driver.findElement(By.id("login-email")).sendKeys(Email);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 80);
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("password")));
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(Password);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='submit']")).click();
```